# Accessing JSON from public folder in ReactApp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have a a JSON file which I would like to use its content into my React App.

This is an excerpt from my code

```
export default class App extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        entry : []
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `./js/data.json`)
    .then(res => res.json())
     .then(json => this.setState({ entry: json }));
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.state.entry.map( x => (
                    <li>
                        <div className='centering'>
                            <span>
                                <img alt='' key={x.img} src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `./img/${x.img}.jpg`}/>
                            </span>
                            <span className='txt'>
                                { x.date }
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <p>{ x.ctx }</p>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div className='hr-line'></div>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

this is the content of my data.json

```
{
"entry" : {
    "2" : [
        {
            "date":"1/1/1",
            "img":"profile",
            "ctx":"as"
        }

    ],
    "1" : [
        {
            "date":"1/1/1",
            "img":"profile",
            "ctx":"as"
        }

    ]
}
```

When I save the file, on the browser it shows `TypeError: this.state is null`
on`render` `{this.state.entry.map (x => ...`

Is there something missing, or it is impossible to do so?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: which line is the error referring to? I don't see how it can be any of the lines of code you've shared here. You'll have to share more of your component.

Comment: I have edited the codes, please take a look.

Comment: Thank you. But the code is out of order (the `constructor` and `componentDidMount` are surely inside the class), and I fear it's still incomplete. Most importantly, you haven't answered my questions about which line is the error referring to. This is the absolute most important first thing to check whenever you get an error like this, asking others to help debug for you without giving this information is just making their life unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot on the error report.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm afraid I have no idea what is causing this. There should be no way `this.state` can be `null` when that line runs,because you've initialised the state as an object in your constructor. Is there some more context that you've not shared?

Comment: That's all of my code that I am currently testing, that's why I am also confused as well.

Answer (score 0):

React expects the ***.map*** for iterative rendering to work on an array of items only.

Therefore, changing the json input to return an array of items will help resolve the problem.

**Existing input that does not work with .map:**

```
"entry" : { "1" : [....], "2" : [....] }   --> Input is not an array of items.
                                           --> .map does not support this format
```

**How to make it work with .map?**

```
"entry" : [ {"1" : {....} , {"2" : {....} ]    --> Input is an array of items. 
                                                --> .map works with this format
```

**Additional: How to avoid 'null value' error in render method?**

The render method must explicitly check for null condition before trying to render elements. This can be done as follows:

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                { (this.state.entry) && 
                  this.state.entry.map( x => (
                    <li>
                        ...
                    </li>
                  ))
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Still not working, it shows the same `TypeError: this.state is null` `render {this.state.entry.map (x => ...`

Comment: An explicit check for null must be added in the render. That will fix the 'null value' issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering is done before componentDidmount. You need to wait for your data to load before to do your map. Something like :

```
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          entry : [],
          anyData: false
      }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      fetch(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `./js/data.json`)
      .then(res => res.json())
       .then(json => this.setState( prevState => ({ ...prevState, entry: json, anyData: true })));
  }

  render(){
     if(!anyData) {
       return <Loader />
     }

      return(
          <div>
              <ul>
                  {this.state.entry.map( x => (...))}
              </ul>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
```

There is also a possibility to use async lifecycle method :

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const res = await fetch(...);
  const json  = await res.json();
  this.setState( prevState => ({ ...prevState, entry: json, anyData: true }));
}
```

But it does not change the fact that it will be done after rendering.

Comment: Now it throws `TypeError: this.state.entry.map is not a function`

Comment: This may result in a better user experience but is irrelevant to the actual question, which is why `this.state` is `null`

Comment: @Nicholas As someone said in the comment section of you question, you data must be in an array. You can try `Array.from(this.State.entry)` to convert it as an array, or 'reshape' it when you set your value in your state

Comment: @RobinZigmond You're right, but for me the only way for this message to appear is that either the state.entry is declared as null or set as null in the componentDidMount. I should have said that in my post